# SQL Разделить ряды на колнки

Tags: sql, join, split

```
SELECT
  D.Name AS Department,
  LastName,
  FirstName,
  PhoneNumber,
  EmailAddress,
  PType.Name AS PhoneType
FROM Person.Person AS Person
LEFT JOIN Person.PersonPhone AS Phone
  ON Person.BusinessEntityID = Phone.BusinessEntityID
LEFT JOIN Person.EmailAddress AS Email
  ON Person.BusinessEntityID = Email.BusinessEntityID
LEFT JOIN HumanResources.EmployeeDepartmentHistory AS DH
  ON Person.BusinessEntityID = DH.BusinessEntityID
LEFT JOIN HumanResources.Department AS D
  ON DH.DepartmentID = D.DepartmentID
LEFT JOIN Person.PhoneNumberType AS PType
  ON Phone.PhoneNumberTypeID = PType.PhoneNumberTypeID
```

Результат: Department, LastName,FirstName,PhoneNumber,EmailAddress,PhoneType.
Нужно: соединить JOIN так, чтоб последняя колнока PhoneType, была поделена на 3 вида телефоноф Cell, Work, Home в 3 колнки, а не одну.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72971/discussion-on-question-by-olyaneko-sql----).

Comment: А хороший вопрос. Можно сделать через iif и group by.

Comment: GROUP BY  Телефонов? или людей? пробовала и так и так есть повторения

Comment: Наоборот, всего кроме телефонов.

Answer (score 1):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7776e6/3

Рассмотрим таблицу такого вида (у тебя получается нечто аналогичное)

```
┌──────┬────────┬──────────────────┬───────────┐
│ name │  role  │ phone            │ phonetype │
├──────┼────────┼──────────────────┼───────────┤
│ John │ Admin  │ +7 123 456 HO ME │ Home      │
│ John │ Admin  │ +7 123 456 WO RK │ Work      │
│ Jake │ Author │ +7 987 654 HO ME │ Home      │
│ Petr │ User   │ +7 000 000 WO RK │ Work      │
└──────┴────────┴──────────────────┴───────────┘
```

Функция `if` (в MySql) или `iif` (в MS SQL) позволяет разнести телефоны на 2 колонки:

```
if(phonetype = N'Home', phone, null) as Home,
if(phonetype = N'Work', phone, null) as Work
```

Теперь делаем группировку по всем остальным полям, а из этого выбираем максимум:

```
select
  name, role,
  max(if(phonetype = N'Home', phone, null)) as Home,
  max(if(phonetype = N'Work', phone, null)) as Work
from smth
group by name, role;
```

и получаем желаемый результат:

```
┌─────┬────────┬──────────────────┬──────────────────┐
│name │ role   │ Home             │ Work             │
├─────┼────────┼──────────────────┼──────────────────┤
│Jake │ Author │ +7 987 654 HO ME │                  │
│John │ Admin  │ +7 123 456 HO ME │ +7 123 456 WO RK │
│Petr │ User   │                  │ +7 000 000 WO RK │
└─────┴────────┴──────────────────┴──────────────────┘
```

**Тут предполагается, что существует не более одного телефона каждого вида.**
Если телефонов одного вида у одного человека может быть несколько, то часть данных будет потеряна при таком преобразовании.

Comment: Да, в моих данных есть несколько тел одного вида, так что это не сработает. Сделала тоже с join Max и grupp by (без IF) но не уверенна если это верно. Так как некоторые люди исчезли из данных.

Comment: @olyaneko, а какой-нибудь `group_concat` использовать можно?

Comment: Не за знаю, что такое group_contact. Я только учусь. По заданию мы только join используем сейчас и самые basic вещи.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй через вложенные запросы сделать.

```
SELECT
  D.Name AS Department,
  LastName,
  FirstName,
  PhoneNumber,
  EmailAddress,
  q.Mobile_phone,
  q2.work_phone,
  q3.my_phone
FROM Person.Person AS Person
LEFT JOIN Person.PersonPhone AS Phone
  ON Person.BusinessEntityID = Phone.BusinessEntityID
LEFT JOIN Person.EmailAddress AS Email
  ON Person.BusinessEntityID = Email.BusinessEntityID
LEFT JOIN HumanResources.EmployeeDepartmentHistory AS DH
  ON Person.BusinessEntityID = DH.BusinessEntityID
LEFT JOIN HumanResources.Department AS D
  ON DH.DepartmentID = D.DepartmentID
LEFT JOIN (SELECT
  PType.Name AS Mobile_phone,
  PType.PhoneNumberTypeID
FROM Person.PhoneNumberType AS PType
WHERE ptype.name = 'Mobile') q
  ON Phone.PhoneNumberTypeID = q.PhoneNumberTypeID
LEFT JOIN (SELECT
  PType.Name AS work_phone,
  PType.PhoneNumberTypeID
FROM Person.PhoneNumberType AS PType
WHERE ptype.name = 'work') q2
  ON Phone.PhoneNumberTypeID = q2.PhoneNumberTypeID
LEFT JOIN (SELECT
  PType.Name AS my_phone,
  PType.PhoneNumberTypeID
FROM Person.PhoneNumberType AS PType
WHERE ptype.name = 'my') q3
  ON Phone.PhoneNumberTypeID = q3.PhoneNumberTypeID
```